# Gitlab-ci, image debian:jessie. Can't change user with su command

Tags: debian, gitlab, gitlab-ci, su, debian-jessie

I'm using Gitlab-ci for my job with Debian jessie image. Firstly, I need install some packages. Everything is ok. Then, I want to change user from root to a non-root user, but su command doesn't work.
Below is a test about changing user.

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: debian:jessie

test:
    script:
    - whoami
    - adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" builder
    - su -l builder
    - whoami
```

My result:

```
$ whoami
root
$ adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" builder
Adding user `builder' ...
Adding new group `builder' (1000) ...
Adding new user `builder' (1000) with group `builder' ...
Creating home directory `/home/builder' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
$ su builder
$ whoami
root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer for myself:

```
 image: debian:jessie

 test:
     script:
     - whoami
     - adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" builder
     - su -l builder
-    - whoami
+    - su builder -c "whoami"
```

Using command `su <username> -c "<command>"` will help running command with `<username>` user, in case mentioned.